# Recursive call in try-catch block to retry N number of times

Tags: java, recursion

I have a regular, non-static `sendMail` method which may occasionally fail. I need to catch any errors and retry the method N number of times. I'm not sure I'm doing the right thing, and there's also a compilation error:

```
public void sendMail(List<String> params) {

   try {
       //...

       static int retrycount = 0; // static not allowed here (but need to keep static var for recursion)
       int maxretries = 3;
   }
   catch (Exception e) {
       log.info(e);
       // Recursion to retry
       sendMail(params);
       retrycount++;
   }
}
```

First of all, is recursion from a try/catch block correct? Also, is there a better way to do this?

I can't make the `sendMail` method static, there are too many references to it in the existing code.

Comment: Instead of using a static variable, why not just pass the current number of tries as a parameter to `sendMail()`?

Comment: I'd prefer not to modify the signature of the method as it's used widely in the existing code.

Comment: Then just make a wrapper method `public void sendMail(List<String> params) { sendMail(params, 0); }`.  Alternately use a loop for retry instead of recursion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your retry will never work in the first place because inside every try block you are setting retrycount to 0.

You'd probably be better off throwing the exception instead of catching it. Then using some kind of a while loop till it completes, maybe with a configurable delay between retries. Or if you're using Spring there is the `Retryable` annotation.

```
void someMethod(){
  int attempts = 0;
  while(attemps <= 3){
    try {
      sendMail(...);
      break;
    } catch (Exception e){
      attempts++;
      // Log failed to send mail or something meaningful, maybe add a delay here?
    } 
  }
}
```

This solution is much cleaner than using recursion as if you wanted to retry many times, eventually you'd get a stack overflow error. It also keeps the responsbility of the sendMail function simple, and avoids adding complicated retry logic to an otherwise simple method.

Also, if you end up having to make other methods retryable in the same fashion then it would be much easier to abstract away the retry logic into some kind of executor service that handles it all.

Answer (score 5):

The standard recursive solution would be to add `retryCount` as a paremeter.

```
public void sendMail(List<String> params) {
    sendMail(params, 0);
}
private void sendMail(List<String> params, int retryCount) {

   try {
       //...

       int maxRetries = 3;
   } catch (Exception e) {
       log.info(e);
       // Recursion to retry
       sendMail(params, retryCount+1);
   }
}
```

A loop would be the more idiomatic way of writing this.

```
public void sendMail(List<String> params) {
    int maxTries = 4;
    for (int tryCount=0; tryCount<maxTries; ++tryCount) {
        try {
            //...
            break;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.info(e);
            // continue to retry
        }
    }
}
```

In the spirit of the original question, the `retryCount` can be kept as a field within an introduced object. It's easiest (if slightly obscure) to do this with an anonymous inner class.

```
public void sendMail(List<String> params) {
    int maxTries = 4;
    new Object() {
        int tryCount = 0;
        public void sendMail() {
            try {
                //...
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.info(e);
                // Recursion to retry
                if (tryCount < maxTries) {
                    ++tryCount;
                    sendMail();
                }
            }
        }
    }.sendMail();
}
```

Comment: The variable name says "**re**try", which means that `retryCount = 0` is 1 attempt, `retryCount = 1` is 2 attempts, and so forth.

Comment: @Andreas Yeah, probably makes more sense to count tries than retries.

Comment: Thanks a lot I chose your While-Loop solution which is your 2nd example. Same answer as Adam's below, working great.

Answer (score 4):

What if you just wrapped the code in a retry loop:

```
public void sendMail(List<String> params) {
  for (int attempt = 0; attempt < 3; attempt++)
   try {
       //...

       if (<some success condition>)
          return;
   }
   catch (Exception e) {
       log.info(e);
   }
}
```